# Mark in word and margin in paragraph

Tags: margins, superscripts

Anyone knows how to put a mark on a word?

(1) Text:
  (1) will be slightly raised as if an exponent.

Also, how could shorten margins in a paragraph? Clip 10 mm left and 10 mm right?

Comment: `text\footnote{footnote here}`?

Comment: footnote include note in footer. i want insert only mark.

Comment: `\textsuperscript{(1)}`

Comment: It depends on what you're using. I'd think that Plain TeX, LaTeX, and ConTeXt each has different ways of doing the same thing. For the shorter margins, I'd suggest \leftskip=10mm and \rightskip=10mm

Comment: LaTeX solution for changing margins: `\usepackage{chngpage}`, and in your text: `\begin{adjustwidth}{10mm}{10mm} ... text ... \end{adjustwidth}`.

Comment: @faisbu For future reference: when you have two unrelated problems like you have, it's better if you ask two separate questions, rather than grouping them into a single question. It just makes it a bit easier for future visitors to find the information they might want.

Answer (score 4):

If you want a mark in your text, you have several approaches.

1. Use `\textsuperscript{(1)}`, as mentioned by Werner
2. Use mathmode (not my favorite solution, but works as well).
3. I don't know if applies, but a *mark* could also be an emphasize... so you can use `\emph{word}`.

For the margins, I wasn't sure what do you want, so I also have two possible answers:

1. Use `\usepackage{chnpage}` and `\begin{adjustwidth}{10mm}{10mm} ... text ... \end{adjustwidth}`, as mentioned by jon in the comments
2. For global margins, go with the `geometry` package and define your margins, e.g. `\usepackage[outer=10mm,inner=10mm,vmargin=10mm]{geometry}`.
3. You could also set the paragraph inside a `minipage` environment and set the width as you want.